# Show custom progress bar in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I know this is common to ask, but yet I still don't know how to call the XML file. I'm just confused about how can I implement the proper calling progress bar when going to another activity. Yet there are lots of resources on site but I think this is different. All I want is When I click the button from first Activity I want to call the progress bar which separately designs as XML and then it goes to the second activity, whether it will set Visible etc. It is possible?

Reference spinKit: [Github](https://github.com/ybq/Android-SpinKit/tree/master/sample/src/main/res)

**When clicking the button in first activity it will pop the spin XML and then dismiss when second activity is already loaded.**

[image]
[image]

**MainActivity**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button clickButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        clickButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttons);
        clickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**ActivityMain**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Click"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Spinkit class**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity; 
public class Spinkit extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loadingspin);

        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.spin_kit);
        Sprite cubeGrid = new CubeGrid();
        progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(cubeGrid);
    }
}
```

**Spinkit xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.SpinKitView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/spin_kit"
        style="@style/SpinKitView.Large.CubeGrid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:SpinKit_Color="@color/white"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
    
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LOADING"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:shadowColor="@color/black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Normally it takes milliseconds to change activity. Do you want to show this progressbar for this milliseconds time?

Comment: @shafayat hossain Thanks for response, Yes I think that's the best way

Comment: @shafayat hossain
Is anyone know how can I implement this?

Comment: There is no "REAL WAY" to do this between activity transition. You can do this between fragment transitions. I would suggest to use fragments instead of activities if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have two activity. And now you want to show animation when changing activity. A professional Android App Developer chooses to use fragment since fragment makes thing easier. Since you are using activity hence I will include information of activity.

You directly can't show that animation. You must add an activity (you can directly code even if you want you can use layout either whatever you prefer).

Someone had mentioned in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69536978/show-custom-progress-bar-in-android-studio#comment122909381_69536978) that "it takes milisec to change activity". But if you want to delay than you can do that.

At first create an activity as [another person](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69543144/16897106) said. Design it however you want. Then use the following code to change activity.

In MainActivity :

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashScreenActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
//If you don't want user to back to the page by clicking back button then use finish();
finish();
```

In SplashScreenActivity :

```java
//Use SpinKit however they have introduced https://github.com/ybq/Android-SpinKit#usage
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress);
Sprite doubleBounce = new DoubleBounce();
progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(doubleBounce);
new Handler().postDelayed(() ->{ 
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
},1000);
//1000 is millisecond if you want to delay 10 sec than write 10000 instead of 1000
```

Here's a related [git repo](https://github.com/Istiakshovon/SplashScreenAndDataPass/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/istiak/doctorinformation/SplashActivity.java#L22-L28)

---

If you want to call SplashScreen while changing every single page than just a data with intent.

In your activity :

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(this,SplashScreenActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("data","home");
startActivity(intent);
```

In SplashScreenActivity :

```java
//write it in global variable
Sprite doubleBounce = new DoubleBounce();
ProgressBar progressBar;

//onCreate method
progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress);

Intent intent = getIntent();
String activity = intent.getStringExtra("data");
if(activity.equals("home")){
   changeActivity(homeActivity.class);
}else if(activity.equals("secondActivity")){
   changeActivity(secondActivity.class);
}

//Another class
private void changeActivity(Class activity){
   progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(doubleBounce);
   new Handler().postDelayed(() ->{
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,activity);
                startActivity(intent);
   },1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, it works fine, but what if I have 3 `Activities`, and I want to call again the `SplashScreenActivity`, not just the `HomeActivity.class` but in different classes, it is possible? to recycle it? without using fragments?

Comment: @ShainnahJane I have edited my answer. I was using class to shorten the code. I think if you want you can directly send class using `intent.putExtra();` I haven't try it so I am leaving it to you..

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it.

1. Create another activity named anything you want for loading.Eg - `LoadingActivity`
2. Make a layout file looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Klk9X.png) or however you want.
3. Then in the java class add this code in the onCreate

   ```
   ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.spin_kit);
   Sprite cubeGrid = new CubeGrid();
   progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(cubeGrid);

   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(this,OtherActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
   ```
4. Done!

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm just wondered but what if I have 3 `Activities`, and I want to call again the `SplashScreenActivity`, not just the `HomeActivity.class` but in different classes, it is possible? to recycle it? without using fragments?

Comment: I did not get what you are trying to tell.Please edit to make it clear.

Comment: This line `startActivity(new Intent(this,OtherActivity.class));`  when using `Intent` , We all knew this is static, the class after it loads it will go to `OtherActivity.class` but what if I have many activities, not just the `OtherActivity.class`. I want to recycled the `SplashScreenActivity` instead of making lot of `SplashScreenActivity` is that possible?